# Serialized form data causes uncaught JS exception, when text field contains ")"

Tags: jquery, serialization

I have the following snippet bound to the submit button

```
            var formData = $(this).serialize();  
            console.log(formData);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'event_crud.php',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'text',
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {   
                    $.mobile.changePage($("#events"));
                    console.log("Data: "+data+"\n Rebuild the list");
                    update(fromDate, toDate, eventList);    
                    $("ul#event-list").listview("refresh");
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("Whoops! Update event failed! "+data);
                }
            });
```

I get an error appearing in my js console, when a text field in the submitted form contains a closing bracket - i.e. a ")" - note, I don't get an exception for the opening bracket, and it doesn't matter where in the text field the ) appears (doesn't need to be at the end)

Here's an example of the serialized form data

```
action=update&eventID=416&type=expense&description=Shopping+)&date=2013-10-17&value=350.0000
```

And here's the error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ]&date=2013-10-17&value=350.0000')
```

Note that the closing bracket has been serialized as a square bracket.
FWIW, the error reference is to jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3

I have also tried encoding the input like this

```
formData = encodeURIComponent(formData);
```

without success.

Strangely, the AJAX POST seems to complete successfully (db is updated), but the changePage action is never executed.